# How to define the endpoint of the azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb, azure-emulator

I'm using the azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker and every time my computer reboot, I have a new EndPoint address, so I need to update my web.config with the new URL.

I didn't find how, but I want to know if it's possible to define an EndPoint URL to always have the same URL?

The only documentation I found on this it's from Microsoft on this article, but there is nothing about setting the EndPoint URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#developing-with-the-emulator

There is also nothing on the GitHub of the projet
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker